# How to write Test class to test a field on an attachment or file insert?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Below is the trigger  update a field on an attachment or file insert , can some one suggest a test class for this trigger?

Can some one please help in writing a  @isTest class for below trigger to achieve 100 % code completion

```
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
if(trigger.isAfter) {
    if(trigger.isInsert) {
        ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler.onAfterInsert(trigger.new);
    }
}
}
```

here is the class

```
            public  class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler {

            public static void onAfterInsert(list<ContentDocumentLink> lstCntLinks) {
            set<Id> setTaskIds = new set<Id>();
            list<task> lstTask=new list<task>();
            Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ERT_Task_Record_Type').getRecordTypeId();

            for(ContentDocumentLink clIterator : lstCntLinks) {  
            setTaskIds.add(clIterator.LinkedEntityId);//Set all task id            
            }

            if(!setTaskIds.isEmpty()) {
                    lstTask= [SELECT Id, Name,Attachment_Indicator__c  FROM task WHERE Id IN :setTaskIds and recordtypeid=: recordTypeId ]; //Get all the task 
                }

            for(task varTsk:  lstTask){
            varTsk.Attachment_Indicator__c=true;//Set Attachment Indicator Flag true

            }
            if(lstTask.size()>0){
            update lstTask; //update task
             }
            }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.
Carolyn

Answer (score 0):

We aren't really a code writing service, you might want to hire some consultancy or even post the job on https://appexchange.salesforce.com/developers (it should be vetted by SF themselves, haven't used that part of appexchange personally). It's different if you have specific problem, wrote some code, got stuck with particular problem...

This should give you some ideas how it could be attacked. No promises it'll even compile. It's not pixel perfect, there's no negative test case (linking to task of different record type should not set the flag etc)

but it's a start.

```
@isTest
public with sharing class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerTest {
    @isTest
    public static void testSettingTaskFlag(){
        Task t = new Task(
            Subject = 'unit test here we go',
            RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ERT_Task_Record_Type').getRecordTypeId()
        );
        insert t;

        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'Some document',
            PathOnClient = 'some document.txt',
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...')
        );
        insert cv;

        ContentDocument cd = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE LatestPublishedVersionId = :cv.Id];
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(
            ContentDocumentId = cd.Id,
            LinkedEntityId = t.Id
        );

        Test.startTest();
        insert cdl;
        Test.stopTest();

        Task newTask = [SELECT Attachment_Indicator__c FROM Task WHERE Id = :t.Id];
        System.assert(newTask.Attachment_Indicator__c);
    }
}
```